# future perfect progressive versus future simple

Tags: verbs, word-usage, tenses

This is similar to a question I asked a few days ago.... Is there any difference in meaning between using the future perfect progressive and using the future simple:

Joe will be tired later because he will have been jogging for an hour

Joe will be tired later because he is going jogging for an hour

Comment: They're pretty much equivalent, but the second version carries more "immediacy" (perhaps he's *just about to* go jogging, or there's some other reason why the fact of him going jogging is somehow relevant to the *current* situation, as well as being likely to cause his expected tiredness later).  The first version is more firmly focused on the anticipated future time - when he definitely ***will*** be tired (which may or may not be a good thing from the speaker's point of view, but that's when it will be *relevant*).

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the comment about immediacy, but I also get the sense that your first example has no implication about timing, while the second one does. When I hear, "He is going jogging for an hour" I have little doubt that he has not yet gone jogging. When I hear "He will have been jogging for an hour," however, I have no sense about the timing, and I would say that it's possible he's already out for the jog now.